# Building a program usually build in Linux using the "make" in a VSC Window using WSL

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code, makefile, gdb

I have a Linux C++ program that I build with GNU Make using the "make" command. How can I convert this to a task.json and a launch.json file for debugging on Visual Studio Code with a WSL

Basically the title. I have a directory that I use in Linux, and simply use the "make" command to build my program with a Makefile. But I need to move to Visual studio, I have managed to get it working in the sense that I can now edit code in VS and then head back to my terminal to "make" again and test but debugging in command line with gdb is not fun so I would like to be able to do it in VS but am having trouble configuring the .json's to get it to build and run and debug correctly.

The build only actually generates .exe's which then would need to be run with the debug setting on.

Any help greatly appreciated!

EDIT: In fact I basically just want Visual Studio Code to be able to debug my program. To build it I actually need to run 2 .sh scripts and then the make file. Is there a way I can make this happen in VSC using the build option and then debug it?

Comment: In the moment, you consider to write software which can be compiled on Linux/g++ as well on Windows/Visual Studio, it's time to consider [CMake](https://cmake.org/) seriously. Btw. mentioning `.json` sounds to me like you speak about Visual Studio Code (what you do in text in fact). In your title, you mention Visual Studio. Beside of the confusing naming (chosen by MS), they have less to do with each other except that both are intended to provide IDEs for development.

Comment: FYI: [Visual Studio Code vs. Visual Studio: How to choose](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3436860/visual-studio-code-vs-visual-studio-how-to-choose.html)

Comment: Yes sorry I need it running and debugging in Visual Studio Code. I am currently using GNU Make to build it using simply the "make" command in a linux terminal invoking the Makefile I have. How would I get this to build in Visual Studio Code using a WSL is my question? It is also posible I can switch to Cmake in the Linux terninal. In this case how would I do the same thing but going from "make cmake" to the VSC WSL build.

Comment: I have also updated the title to make it clearer.

Comment: I noticed. Though I don't know nothing about VSC except its name, I googled out of curiosity and found what I actually expected: CMake seems to support VSC as well: [Get started with CMake Tools on Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cmake-linux), [CMake Tools Extension for Visual Studio Code](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cmake-tools-extension-for-visual-studio-code/).

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are asking but I am assuming you run Visual Studio Code on Windows and need to compile and debug a program with the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).

You can do that with the [remote development extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview). The Visual Studio Code C/C++ extension also supports remote development.

This works for WSL but also for compiling and debugging on a Linux server (using SSH).

Comment: I just switched my build to use CMake and used the CMake Tools VSC extension to autodetect my kit and how to build. Thanks though